# How many number of ordering node can take a transaction in Hyper-ledger Fabric?

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger-fabric

When we talk about ordering service in a hyper-ledger fabric architecture,
how many ordering nodes can take up a transaction?

Answer (score 2):

Hyperledger Fabric v1.0 comes with 2 implementations of ordering service types:

- Solo Orderer - mainly for development and testing, that comes with only a single node.
- Kafka Orderer - a set of ordering service nodes that communicate with one another via sending and receiving messages through a cluster of Apache Kafka brokers.

In each of these - a transaction is sent to exactly one ordering service nodes, and it signed by exactly one ordering service node.

Comment: Correct! The reason why is because have a single node of the Orderer type is a single point of failure. If the node is down information can be lost.